# How to check if an user is an admin SECURE

Tags: php, mysql, security, superuser

I made a login function with bruteforce protection, different bot protection functions like honeypot.., input filtering, Argon2 encrypted password.

But in the end to identify the user i save the id inside a session after a successful login.
With this id until now i checked if the column "admin" has the value 1 or 0.

If this value is 1 the user can do everything.

How i could improve the security ? 
How else i could check if a user is an admin ?

Comment: Do you have an issue with the current setup? If you have working code and just want to know if there's a better way, I would recommend posting a question over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. Just a heads up, you need to read their guidelines first.

Comment: No until now everything fine but i guess it could be insecure for the future.

Comment: _"but i guess it could be insecure for the future"_ - If it isn't insecure now, use it. If it turns out that there are some vulnerability with it in the future, think about that then. It's literally impossible to guess what vulnerabilities _might_ pop up in the future.

Comment: Thats the wrong way to prevent damage ;D. Im pretty sure you wont do the same with your life.

Comment: Do you go to the doctor and ask him for medicine before you know what's wrong with you, or even _if_ there's something wrong with you?

Answer (score 0):

You should do as I will direct you

As long as you have user id in act so it's half of the way

I will assume that you have function.php which have all the functions you use in website

Also you have login function that check user account details and give access 
You now need to improve that to restrict user access

First:
Create table in MySQL call it group  this table will have two records or as you like  so. Admin will have id 1 and members id 2  then you can make much modifications like make another column in that table called upload and set admin to yes while members to no

Second in your login function use the following

```
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN group ON users.class=group.group_id WHERE users.enabled='yes' AND users.status = 'confirmed'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
```

Users.class is the group id and users is the table users
Now you can check group credits  as example if on upload page you do the following

```
    if($row["can_upload"]=="no")
    echo("admin only can upload ");
```

You can check credentials on group as you need also you can make much classes like admin , members, uploders, reviewers,authors and give every class special permissions as website content is viewed

On admin.php you can use

```
    if($row["admin"]=="no")
    ech("admin only can view this page ");
```

In both examples above   Admin and can_upload is colum in group table and it's changed by user class .

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please explain me because a different table is more secure then a column inside a table to check superuser ? May it secure better from sql injections ?

Comment: Yes as long as you make more check on user based on class this add another security layer to application. My advice is to make much more check on login cookies try to make it more secure as many attacks on application is still around cookies. There's many tutorials around this especially using salt keys like word press does.

Comment: There's no reason to be writing new code with `mysql_query` in 2019. It doesn't even exist in PHP 7.

Comment: I know it's depreciated . I don't use php 7 at all I don't like it . It's for new school of science graduates. But for professional .. old is gold.

Comment: For professionals, old is *unsupported and insecure* in PHP's case, and thus **un**professional. "I don't like it" is a childish and silly attitude. [Only PHP 7 is currently supported](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php).

Comment: Good point of view and this is just answer not php elections.  Centos old version is still used and it's unsupported also many else. Wikipedia have servers still running on old Linux distributions. Support is not advantage . And security it's still unclear especially for new versions.